# Is there a way to improve the script ? Now it's doing StartCoroutine in StartCoroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is working fine and the result is fine.
The question is if doing StartCoroutine inside StartCoroutine will not make problems with the performance or if it's fine at all to make StartCoroutine inside StartCoroutine ?

I could change the line :

```
StartCoroutine(Rotates(objectsToRotate[i].transform, duration));
```

With

```
yield return Rotates(objectsToRotate[i].transform, duration);
```

But then it will wait for the first object to finish rotating before starting the next one and that's not what I want. I want the objects to start rotating while the others already rotating just with different random starting intervals.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objectsToRotate;
    public float duration = 5f;
    public static bool desiredAngle = false;

    private Vector3 lastFwd;
    private int rotcount = 0;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (rotcount == 0)
        {
            rotcount = 1;
            StartCoroutine(StartRotationOfObjects());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator StartRotationOfObjects()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
        {
            // Random wait period before rotation starts
            if (i == 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0, 2f));
            }

            StartCoroutine(Rotates(objectsToRotate[i].transform, duration));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Rotates(Transform objectToRotate, float duration)
    {
        Quaternion startRot = objectToRotate.rotation;
        float t = 0.0f;
        lastFwd = objectToRotate.transform.forward;

        rotcount++;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;

            objectToRotate.rotation = startRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(t / duration * 360f, Vector3.up);

            var curFwd = objectToRotate.transform.forward;
            // measure the angle rotated since last frame:
            var ang = Vector3.Angle(curFwd, lastFwd);

            if (myApproximation(ang, 179f, 1f) == true)
            {
                desiredAngle = true;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
        objectToRotate.rotation = startRot;

        desiredAngle = false;

        if (rotcount == 4)
            rotcount = 0;
    }

    private bool myApproximation(float a, float b, float tolerance)
    {
        return (Mathf.Abs(a - b) < tolerance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question here? This post may be more appropriate on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Having `Coroutines` starting other `Coroutines` is totally fine.

Of cause it doesn't scale well and potentially creates some hassle if you need to extend the functionality. But as long it's in the given small scope I would just stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the yield in StartRotationOfObjects to the Rotates coroutine, passing down the index as parameter. You would remove one coroutine from the process.

```
private rotcount = 1;
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (rotcount == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
        {
           StartCoroutine(Rotates(i));
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator Rotates(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        yield return null; // no need to create an object that does nothing
    }
    else
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0, 2f));
    }
    Transform objectToRotate = objectsToRotate[i].transform
    Quaternion startRot = objectToRotate.rotation;
    float t = 0.0f;
    lastFwd = objectToRotate.transform.forward;

    rotcount++;

    while (t < duration)
    {
        // Rotation code

        yield return null;
    }
    objectToRotate.rotation = startRot;
    desiredAngle = false;

    if (rotcount == 4){ rotcount = 1; }
}
```

The line about rotcount == 0 and then rotcount =1 is unclear. It makes the rotcount at 0 useless since it will increased right away.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is perfectly reasonable. Potentially you could add a delay parameter to Rotates(), which would allow you to flatten the coroutines; IMO, the way you've split the concerns is a nicer way to do it.

At the point where you invoke:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
```

you are introducing a 1 frame delay, which may or may not be of concern to you. You could just as well directly start the first iteration of Rotates() from there, should it suit your needs.